# How to get nicematrix diagonal dots in the right place

Tags: formatting, matrices, nicematrix

I'm trying to write a matrix with dots in it using the [nicematrix](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/nicematrix/nicematrix.pdf) package. I'm struggling to get the dots in the right place. My current best attempt looks like this:
[image: Best attempt with problem marked]

The lower triangle of the matrix consists of zeros, which are nicely connected by dots to make a triangle. The diagonal is filled with the term CA^{-1}B. I need those diagonal dots to connect nicely, as they do with the zeros. I think the current diagonal dots that I have marked are aimed towards the rule above the target rule, but I'm not sure of this. An MWE of my best attempt is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,nicematrix}

\begin{document}
$\begin{bNiceMatrix}[nullify-dots] CA^{-1}B & CA^{-2}B & \Cdots & CA^{-p}B & CA^{-(p+1)}B \\
0 & CA^{-1}B & \Cdots & CA^{-(p-1)}B & CA^{-p}B \\
\Vdots & \Ddots & \Ddots & \Vdots & \Vdots \\
& & & CA^{-1}B & CA^{-2}B \\
0 & \Cdots & & 0 & CA^{-1}B \end{bNiceMatrix}$
\end{document}
```

How do I make the diagonal dots behave nicely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are seeing is a consequence of the fact that `nicematrix` draws lines of diagonal dots parallel to each other. The first such line drawn determines the direction (see *Technical remarks*, *Diagonal lines* in the manual). Using `\extrarowheight`, things like `\strut` in matrix elements and `\noalign{\kern -2pt}` between lines, one can influence vertical positioning of rows, and thus how lines with diagonal dots connect to matrix elements. Another possibility is to draw lines with diagonal dots in a different order so as to use another direction for them.

Here is my proposal. `nicematrix` v3.13 or later is required for the `xdots/shorten` option, but if your `nicematrix` version is 3.10, 3.11 or 3.12, you can just replace `xdots/shorten` with `dotted-lines-margin`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

$\setlength{\extrarowheight}{0.5ex}
\begin{bNiceMatrix}[nullify-dots, xdots/shorten=0.5em] CA^{-1}B & CA^{-2}B & \Cdots & CA^{-p}B & CA^{-(p+1)}B \\
0 & CA^{-1}B\strut & \Cdots & CA^{-(p-1)}B & CA^{-p}B \\
\Vdots & \Ddots & \Ddots & \Vdots & \Vdots \\ \noalign{\kern -6pt}
& & & CA^{-1}B & CA^{-2}B \\
0 & \Cdots & & 0 & CA^{-1}B \end{bNiceMatrix}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

The same with `\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1.3ex}` instead of `0.5ex`:

[image]

Comment: In fact, since version 3.13, the option `dotted-lines-margin` has been renamed `xdots/shorten` (and `xdots/color` and `xdots/line-style` have been created for a full customization of the dotted lines).

Comment: Many thanks for your input and this great package! I have updated my answer to work with the latest version. Maybe you could have kept the `dotted-lines-margin` option as a deprecated alias to preserve compatibility. I guess you felt more concerned about avoiding to clutter the code with obsolete, duplicate options... Anyway, you're the maintainer, you decide. :-)

Comment: This is great, thank you both. Your proposal already looks a lot better and you've given me the means to tweak this to my liking.

Comment: You're welcome, glad to be of assistance.